# "We'd known each other too long for hard feelings." Is a correct sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction, grammaticality-in-context

In [Longman Dictionary](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/hard_1) (19) is the following sentence example:

> We'd known each other too long for hard feelings.

The sentence doesn't sound natural to me.  It sounds incomplete at the end. There should be at the end of the sentence the to-infinitive "to exist". Am I correct? Are my sentences below that follow this pattern wrong?

> 1. We'd known each other too long for hard feelings **to exist.**
> 2. I have known him very well for misunderstandings **to occur.**
> 3. The society is very stable and united for a chaos/breakdown **to
>      ensue.**

Comment: The pattern is "*too* X for Y to happen".  **very** <> **too**.  X is *so* great that Y is not possible.  "very" = "greatly".  "very" <> "*so* greatly".

Comment: You could say "I *have known* him too *long* for such a misunderstanding to happen", but you cannot say "I *have known* him too *well*...". This is an interesting question. Please ask it separately.

Comment: **well** is a fascinating word. Well up!  well-done!  Well! Well!

Answer (score 2):

How about *to have*?

> We'd known each other too long **to have** hard feelings.

Regarding the others, the patterns seem OK but some wording changes are needed:

> We'd known each other too long for hard feelings to exist. (OK)
>
> I *know* him *too* well for misunderstandings to occur.
>
> *Society* is very stable and united *to allow* a chaos/breakdown to ensue.

Comment: I agree with your evaluation, but I wouldn't say it is technically wrong.

Comment: Please check my edits.

Comment: Could you please tell me why you thought it was correct to remove the present perfect in the second sentence and to remove the article in the third sentence and with the structure of "For something to-infinitive?

Comment: They are different topics and should be separate questions. #2 we just *know* people; there is no reason for perfect tense. In #3 "society" is a mass noun.